# Source Links When Organizing Websites

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

A little about myself so you know your audience: I recently began learn `HTML` this year and have created my first (quite basic) website. I am well versed in `Python` so I know basic coding terminology.

The issue I am having is that everything is quite cluttered. To clarify, I have one main folder where every single picture and `.html` file is stored. So there are 200 different files (of different types in 1 folder)

What I want is to be able to create folders according to the topics listed on the website. For example, if my homepage has 4 links to 4 different topics, I want to have 4 different folders that each only have the links corresponding to that topic.

I think the problem I am running into is defining a file pathway for each link. Currently, these 4 categories are active images that you can click on and navigate further.

```
a href="Heart Surgery.html"><img src="HeartSurgery.png"
```

What I have done so far is this create a homepage folder. Within it are the 4 folders of the 4 topics, and also a link to the homepage (as well as all images including those of the 4 topics).

When I put the actual `.html` file into one of these categories and change the file path to

```
a href="\HeartSurgery\Heart Surgery.html"><img src="HeartSurgery.png"
```

It just is not working. I have tried specifying further to include the homepage and luck.

Comment: Try relative source paths with . (dot) or ..(double dots) ../folder_name/file_name.html/png/etc. More over, you get better if you use any web framework like django. Else, you may have one folder for all static content like images, js, css files one folder for all html files, one foler for all python files.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Make use of formatting to make the question readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not have spaces in URLs (and file names). If you do, they should be encoded as `%20`.
2. URLs use `/` forward slashes, not backslashes.
3. A URL starting with a `/` forward slash is a root-relative URL, meaning it always refers to a file absolutely from the site root. If you're on `http://example.com/foo/bar`, the link `href="/baz"` always refers to `http://example.com/baz`.
4. Conversely, links without starting slash are relative to the current folder. If you're on `http://example.com/foo/bar`, the link `href="baz"` refers to `http://example.com/foo/baz`. If you're on `http://example.com/foo/bar/` (note trailing slash), the link `href="baz"` refers to `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz`.
5. The same applies to any URLs, including image `src`.

I hope these clarifications and rules help you to organise your links.

Comment: Thank you! Every single point was helpful! Conclusions from point 3 and 4 bridged the gap for me.